# R notebook chunks don't want to evaluate code but still show it

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

we've been trying to show only the code on the R-Notebook using RStudio but so far we are not able to do it.

In theory it's very simple and if you put any of these expresions on the chunk, it will get our dessire output:

{r, eval=FALSE, echo=TRUE}

{r, eval=FALSE}

But we couldn't make it work and right now we're not sure if it's due to a bug on our RStudio Version (Version 1.0.136) or knitr (1.15.1).

Really appreciate any help on this.

Best regards,
Andrés

Answer (score 0):

ignore this question, cause now is working with exactly the same expression:

{r, eval=FALSE}

Not sure what was going on but once I restarted the RStudio it works fine.

Sorry!